# Angular JS Hashbang URL's malformed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angularjs app and I configured my $locationProvider to use hash bangs like so:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';
```

In the html I have a link that is inside of the ng-app directive that looks like this:

`<a href="#!/games">Games</a>`

When I click the link, the url that is displayed by the browser is index.html#/!/games. Notice the slash between the hash and the bang. If I don't use angularjs the url displays as I would expect: /index.html#!/games. Does any body have an idea why the extra slash is being added between the hash and the bang?

Comment: You should be setting hashPrefix with a setter method, not like a property. $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

Answer (score 0):

Per Nicholas comment above, `hashPrefix` is a setter method, so the correct way to configure your `$locationProvider` is like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```